# PHP Solarium library with the unified highlighter

Tags: php, solr, solarium

Can the PHP `Solr` client Solarium be used with the [Unified highlighter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting#Highlighting-TheUnifiedHighlighter)? If so, how? The [Solarium documentation](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/select-query/building-a-select-query/components/highlighting-component/) doesn't list any ways of using it. Only the older highlighters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It currently doesn't support it, so I posted a feature request [here](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/issues/517).